# How to write to child view controller's outlet from super view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

My application includes very similar album pages that draw pictures from web server. Every page has an album title and a table to show pictures. Only difference between pages is http request parameters. 
I collected common behaviours (and data) into a super class "CommonViewController" and then I created child classes (FoodsViewController, BeveragesViewController) inherited from CommonViewController. I'll call child view controllers using their "story board id" from menu and then pass http request parameters to super class CommonViewController.

I placed child view controllers to story board and created outlets to labels and table views for each child view controller using mouse (cntrl+left click).

Child view controllers fill their request parameters to a struct that is defined in CommonViewController then it fetches the pictures from server.

The outlets is located in child view controllers but data is producing in super class. 
CommonViewController doesn't know that which outlet will be written. How could I write data to outlets which is located in child view controllers from super class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have collected your data in `CommonViewController` call a method such as `[self processData:receivedData];` where `receivedData` is the structure you want to process in the child - I will just use an `NSData` instance for this example.

You can *simulate* an abstract method by having the following in your `commonViewController` implementation of `processData`:

CommonViewController.m:

```
-(void) processData:(NSData *)receivedData
{
   NSAssert(NO,@"Override processData in your subclass");
}
```

Then in each of your subclasses, override the method to perform whatever is required:

FoodsViewController.m:

```
-(void) processData:(NSData *)receivedData
   {
       //TODO put the data into the right controls
   }
```

**Update**

If the mapping of data to the visual controls is the same (i.e. there is always a "title Label" and a "item picture" for example, but their placement on the screen changes, then you can define the control properties in your superclass.h -

```
@property (weak,nonatomic)  IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;
@property (weak,nonatomic)  IBOutlet UIImageView *itemPicture;
```

Then when you create use a subclass as your UIViewController in InterfaceBuilder you can just drag the connection from the control to the IBOutlet.  If you are creating your controls programatically rather than in IB, then you can just assign them to the property in the subclass -

```
  [self.view addSubView:myTitleLabel];
  self.titleLabel=myTitleLabel;
```

In this case you can omit the IBOutlet

Comment: But this method cause repeated code because processData would be same for all subclasses.

Comment: Isn't there a method to pass outlets from child classes to superclass ?

Comment: If the outlet names are the same in all classes then just define them in the superclass and assign them in the subclass views in the storyboard, bur you said that `CommonViewController` "doesn't know which outlets will be written" which implied to me that the code isn't the same in all sub classes

Comment: How can I do it programmatically without using storyboard?

Comment: "@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;"
"@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *returnedText;" I created two outlets in super class. How could i assign them to subclass views?

Comment: I added below lines to subclass views but it didn't worked   `self.tableView.delegate = self;
 self.tableView.dataSource = self;`

Comment: Define the IBOutlet properties in your superclass.  In the storyboard scene for your sub view, change the object type for the view controller to the appropriate subclass.  Control drag from the control to the "view controller" object or drag from "New referencing outlet" to the view controller object - the IBOutlets you defined in the superclass should appear.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50931/discussion-between-paulw11-and-zontragon)